# woocommerce expired products custom post_status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, http-status-code-404

I extended the product post type of `woocommerce` to have a custom `post_status` called 'expired'.

The desired behavior is to publish a product to the shop and set it to expired after a certain time span.

Only published products should be visible in the shop but the permalink to a product should still be working after the post_status is set to expired but display a different template.

Woocommerce itself only displays products(in the shop and single product view) with the "publish" `post_status` by default so my initial thought was to simply hook into `pre_get_posts` and add 'expired' to the `post_status` query vars.

A little addition is to use the same slug for posts, products and pages.

http://example.com/page-name

http://example.com/post-name

http://example.com/product-name

To accomplish all this I came up with the following code:

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    'custom_pre_get_posts'
);

function custom_pre_get_posts($query) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $post_name = $query->get('name')) {

        $result = $wpdb->get_row(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT post_type, ID, post_status FROM '.$wpdb->posts.' WHERE post_name = %s LIMIT 1',
                $post_name
            )
        );



        if(!empty($result) && $result->post_type == 'product'){
            $query->set('name', $post_name);
            $query->set('product', $post_name);
            $query->set('post_type', $result->post_type);
            $query->set('post_status', $result->post_status);               
        }


    }

}
```

Just manually checking if a post with the given name exists and what post_status it has. After that the query vars are set accordingly.

And to include a custom template for expired products:

```
add_filter( 
    'template_include', 
    'custom_expired_templates', 
    99 
);

function custom_expired_templates($template){

    global $wp_query;
    $status = $wp_query->get('post_status');
    $type = $wp_query->get('post_type');

    if($status === 'expired' && $type ==='product'){
        $template = locate_template( array( 'woocommerce/expired-single-product.php' ) );
    }

    return $template;
}
```

`woocommerce/expired-single-product.php` is just a plain copy of `woocmmerce/single-product.php` in my theme directory.

The above code works... but it seems kind of hacky to do it this way since the custom template gets display but wordpress sends a 404 header and the title gets set to 'page not found' so I'm basically overwriting the 404-template.

A side effect is that the woocommerce styles and scripts won't load. I really tried to dig into the documentation of woocommerce but I was not able to isolate the error.

Any recommendations on a proper way to accomplish the desired behavior?

**Update**

Verified the resulting SQL query by adding

```
add_action('the_posts','test_sql_request');

function test_sql_request($posts){
    echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request;
    var_dump($posts);
    return $posts;
}
```

The expired product has the SQL request:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_name = 'expired-product' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'expired')) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

but it returns an empty array. Running the exact query in phpmyadmin returned the right post. The query for the publish product looks identical except for post_status and name (selfexplainatory) ... but returns the right post in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the failure was not in the code posted above but in the registration of the `post_status` itself:

```
function my_custom_post_status(){

    register_post_status( 'expired', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'expired', 'product' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Expired <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Expired <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
    ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_status' );
```

The problematic part is

```
 'public' => false
```

and has to be changed to

```
'public' => true
```

I didn't know that the public attribute affects querying even when you query the ID. The expired product has the ID 103 and  `$post = new WP_Query('p=103');`  doesn't return a single post where `$post = get_post(103);` does return the correct post.

Maybe this prevents some future headaches for someone in a similar situation.